# Basic authentication with geb

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, groovy, geb

Iam using selenium and geb to automate tests, I need to pass basic authentication parameters, been searching but so far I have no idea how to do it, I've tried:

```
import geb.Page
import geb.Browser
class testOne extends Page{
  static url = 'http://username:password@testUrl.com'
}
```

but that doesnt work, any help is apreciated

Comment: Of course I googled this, been researching and triying to solve this problem for 2 days

Comment: How do you know that your application using  basic authentication ?

Comment: @yosuvaA because I implemented it

Comment: do you have any error? edit question and provide more information.

Comment: @NilsonLagos Can i get the URL? so that i can try and let you know

Comment: According to RFC 3986, embedded user and password in the URL is deprecated, which is why IE and Edge do not support it, see also this article. The behaviour for those two browsers described there I could reproduce in my tests. For other browsers such as Chrome, Opera, Firefox, PhantomJS, HtmlUnit this is still working with Selenium Webdriver and thus also with Geb. I tried all browsers I mentioned. Which browser are you using?